# Create a 3D xarray (lat,long and time) from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a dataframe that has for each row a timestep, latitude, longitude and the values of the variables. So there exists a repetition of values since we have a row for each day and each latitude and longitude combination. like that:

[Initial dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea0OO.png)

I want to create a 3D xarray that have as dimensions: time (from 1951 to 2023), longitude and latitude and then the value of the variable.

I tried to construct the dataarray with xr.dataarray but it does not recognize the time as dimensions, since there is a repetition of time values and lat and long I think.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use something like:

```
data_array = xr.DataArray(data=df['precipitation'].values,
                      dims=('time', 'lat', 'lon'),
                      coords={'time': df['time'].values,
                              'lat': df['lat'].values,
                              'lon': df['lon'].values})
```

and got an error saying the time dimension is not recognized or the code did not run at all? If it is the first case, try with `pandas.to_datetime`. If it is the second case, can you provide more information on your error message?

Comment: Using that command I have this error: 
ValueError: different number of dimensions on data and dims: 1 vs 3

I tried to use this code:

df_subset = df_subset.set_index(['Time', "Longitude", "Latitude"])

ds = df_subset.to_xarray()
And it create the xarray but it seems it does not manage to pick the value of the variable for the lat - lon combinations. If I try to print the map for a specific time it does not plot a map, so a value for 'for each pixel' but just some random points.

Comment: It's possibly because the 'precip' is still a one column data, reshape df['precip'] to an array with the same size as (['Time', "Longitude", "Latitude"]), then apply the xr.DataArray.